# Вездесущие предлоги В и НА

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика, предлоги

Разбейте сочетания на группы на основании общего правила выбора и для каждой группы сформулируйте это правило.

(Кататься на лыжах) в Альпах, (поселиться) в Гималаях, (конференция) в Индии, (фотографировать медведей) на Камчатке, (отдыхать) в Карпатах, (лечиться) на Северном Кавказе, (побывать) на Кипре, (трудиться) на Кубе, (родиться) в России, (работать) на Тайване, (город) на Урале, (изучать язык) в Японии.

Подчиняются ли сочетания (гостить) в Гренландии, (учиться) в Италии, (искать полезные ископаемые) в Кордильерах, (жить) в Крыму, (плантации) на Мадагаскаре сформулированным правилам? Если какое-либо (какие-либо) из сочетаний подчиняется (подчиняются) этим правилам, то какому именно из них? Если не подчиняются, то какое правило не соблюдено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правил для гарантированно верного выбора нет, но закономерности уже сложившегося употребления предлогов выявить можно.

В горах (в Альпах, в Гималаях, в Кордильерах, в Карпатах)
В стране (в России, в Японии, в Италии)
На острове (на Кубе, на Мадагаскаре, на Тайване, на Кипре - вкл. одноимённые островные государства)
На полуострове (на Камчатке, на Ямале)
На условной территории (на Кавказе, на Урале, на Брянщине, на Украине)
В особенном месте, провинции (в Крыму, в Гренландии, в Лапландии, в Курляндии)

Comment: А  почему  в  Ирландии (государство и  остров),  но  на  Кубе (государство  и  остров)?  Почему  в  Сибири,  но  на  Дальнем  Востоке?  Считаю,  что  Тина  права.

Answer (score 1):

Да нет никаких правил - так исторически сложилось. В этом же вся прелесть! Когда иностранец учит язык, он пробует выявить правила, хотя бы мнемонические, чтобы ориентироваться в этой, чужой для него, стихии. А мы, носители языка, впитываем это знание из воздуха, без усилий, с самого нежного возраста.  Главное - это бесплатно доставшееся богатство не расплескать, как это сделали многие медиа-лица, дружно забывшие русский язык в угоду властям Украины. И ведь не помогло! Всякое предательство бьет рикошетом по самому предателю, а предать свой язык = единственное, что пока еще связывает нашу страну в единое целое и даже «ближнее зарубежье» делает к нам ближе = это самое идиотское харакири, на которое способна наша власть.